# Android Studio, populating a list view with 4 random elements using a GET from a PHP database file

Tags: java, android-studio

I am doing a project where I am creating a (very) simple workout generator app that lets you log in, you are then prompted to choose a push, pull, or leg workout. This takes you to another screen where it should generate a routine that consists of 4 workouts that are randomly selected from an array within a PHP file using a GET function.

so my question is:
How do I create the list and then fill the list with the array elements?
Im just kind of lost here thanks!

here is what my Pull workout fragment looks like if that helps.

```
package com.example.workoutapp;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.workoutapp.model.PushWorkoutModel;
import com.example.workoutapp.model.WorkoutFormatRequest;
import com.example.workoutapp.model.WorkoutReps;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link pullWorkoutFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class pullWorkoutFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public pullWorkoutFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment pullWorkoutFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static pullWorkoutFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        pullWorkoutFragment fragment = new pullWorkoutFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pull_workout, container, false);

        view.findViewById(R.id.pullBackButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Navigation.findNavController(view).popBackStack();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```